# How to send Monero from a cold (paper) wallet via RPC?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, cold-storage, transfer

I'm generating a wallet address and keys with http://moneroaddress.org. But how can I create, sign and send transactions with NodeJS from this cold wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `monero-wallet-rpc` requires a wallet *file* to operate on. Therefore, if you only have the keys, you will first need to restore a wallet file from your keys, which can be done using the `monero-wallet-cli`:

```
monero-wallet-cli --generate-from-keys my_wallet
```

This will prompt you for your address and keys then save the new wallet file as `my_wallet`.

You can then proceed to opening the wallet file you just created with the RPC:

```
monero-wallet-rpc --wallet-file my_wallet --rpc-bind-port 18084 ...
```

At which point you can then call the [RPC methods](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html), such as [transfer](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer), to transfer funds.

All the RPC commands are just HTTP POST calls, no special libraries are needed.

Comment: But how another wallets support importing wallet from keys? MyMonero for examle

Comment: MyMonero is not the official Monero wallet. This answer is specifically for the official Monero applications and wallet file & keys.